# shovel eight objects into each array index ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, refactoring, arrayofarrays

Is there a way to refactor this code?  The first snippet is what I currently have and the second is the logic I am trying to churn out.

```
count = 0
until count >= board.length
  if board[count] == nil
    board[count] = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,]
  end
  count += 1
end
board
```

On my 4th line, I want to do something like

```
board[count] = (8.times { board[count] << nil })
```

I know it is just about as long.  I am just curious or want to flush my logic out...thanks!!

Comment: Generally speaking, in Ruby you don't ever need to keep counters. You can easily iterate over lists using `each` or `map`. So, while @Ursus's answer is defo the right one, just for educational purposes, on line 4  you could do something like: `board[count] = (1..8).map { nil }`. Which could then be taken to a higher level: `board.map { (1..8).map { nil } }` for the whole snippet, or something (not sure if that is the intended behaviour).

Comment: I noticed you never accept the answers given to your questions. Make sure to go over your questions some time and accept the best answers given they solve your question. This way you let the community know, that the problem is solved and at the same time you reward the effort of the one, who has provided the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use `Array`'s constructor

```
Array.new(8)
 => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil] 

Array.new(8, 42)
 => [42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
```

and pass a block if you need an object and don't want that each instance is the same

```
Array.new(8) { Hash.new }
 => [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides shortening the assignment to `board[count] = Array.new(8)`, other parts can be written more concise, too:

```
if x == nil
  x = ...
end
```

This is a very common pattern. It can often be written as:

```
x ||= ...
```

This will assign the right-hand side to `x` if `x` is *falsey*, i.e. either `nil` or `false`.

In your example it becomes:

```
board[count] ||= Array.new(8)
```

The explicit counter variable can also be avoided by using [`Array#each_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index). This shrinks your whole `until` block to:

```
board.each_index { |i| board[i] ||= Array.new(8) }
```

To get rid of the index, you could also use [`map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21):

```
board.map! { |e| e || Array.new(8) }
```

This will replace each element `e` with the block's result, which is either just `e` or – if `e` is *falsey* – an array of 8 `nil`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
board[count] = [nil]*8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make a two-dimensional array of size `n` by `m` populated by value `x`:

```
Array.new(n) { Array.new(m, x) }
```

So in your case you can adapt your code to be:

```
Array.new(count) { Array.new(8) }
```

The default value in an array is `nil`.